# Get total number of matches for a regex via standard unix command

Tags: regex, command-line, grep

Let's say that I want to count the number of "o" characters in the text

```
oooasdfa
oasoasgo
```

My first thought was to do `grep -c o`, but this returns `2`, because `grep` returns the number of matching lines, not the total number of matches. Is there a flag I can use with `grep` to change this? Or perhaps I should be using `awk`, or some other command?

Answer (score 5):

This will print the number of matches:

```
echo "oooasdfa
oasoasgo" | grep -o o | wc -l
```

Comment: Was just getting ready to put that, the grep -o parameter displays each match instead of the matching line.  However you cannot use -c and -o together to count the characters, you must pipe it to wc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the shell (bash)

```
$ var=$(<file)
$ echo $var
oooasdfa oasoasgo
$ o="${var//[^o]/}"
$ echo ${#o}
6
```

awk

```
$ awk '{m=gsub("o","");sum+=m}END{print sum}' file
6
```